# How can I drop obs. conditionally to another data frame? R

Tags: r, database, dplyr, tidyverse

Ok, so I have my dataset for firms that seems like this

There are 98688 firms that are shown 6 years

So this data base is

`Balances`

```
Year     FirmID      Sales
2014       A101        3 
2015       A101        5
2016       A101        2
2017       A101        1
2018       A101        3

2014       B107        3 
2015       B107        5
2016       B107        2
2017       B107        1
2018       B107        3
 .          .          .
 .          .          .
 .          .          .
 .          .          .
```

And I have a list that I need to get rid off that list is just like this

`Sacar`

```
FirmID    Sacar
A101      sacar
B107      sacar
.         sacar
.         sacar
.         sacar
```

How would you do it?

I was trying with a left join and then a filter

Comment: Could you show an expected output?

Comment: You can use `anti_join` : `dplyr::anti_join(Balances, Sacar, by = 'FirmID')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Balances %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!FirmID %in% Sacar$FirmID)
```

This should remove all FirmID in Sacar which are there in Balances.

Comment: Yes! It worked, got the same with `left_join`, but your method is way easier